# i want to try to separate the 2 inputs and i want to also input them with different positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

can anyone help, i want to try to separate the 2 inputs and i want to also input them with different positions

my original code:

```
import requests


title = input("Movie tittle:")

URL = ('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+title+'&apikey='+api_key)

req = requests.get(URL)
print(req.status_code)
```

the previous code didn't include the title and year, but now I want the year title to be in the url, what I mean is that I want the url to have the title and year and done with only 1 time input:

```
title = input('Movie tittle:') 

URL = ('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey='+apikey+'&t='+title+'&y='+year)
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please explain what do you mean by separate 2 inputs ?  Also it would be easy if you share expected output you want.

Comment: You could assign the title to a variable called `title` and the year to one called `year` and use the variables when constructing the URL. Also, none of the parentheses in your question do anything and can be left out. What exactly do you mean by "inputs"? Please share your code or describe in more detail how your script needs to behave and what trouble you're having to get it to do so.

Comment: okey i edit my question

Comment: If you want a single line of input to provide you with two different items of data, you'll need to know enough about the input format to be able to split them. Spaces are unlikely to be an acceptable separator, since they can easily be part of a title. But you could add a character between the title and year that is unlikely to be found in the title itself, like a vertical bar (`|`), then `split` on that character.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many ways to do this. Here's an example. The user should enter their data in the format

```
Movie Title (year)
```

To process input in this format:

```
titleyear = input("Movie title: ")

titleyearsplit = titleyear.rsplit('(', maxsplit=1)

# title comes before the year
title = titleyearsplit[0]
# year is between parentheses
year = titleyearsplit[1].rstrip(')')
```

You'll need to add error handling as you feel necessary.